# Stationarity GARCH(p,q) model

Tags: stationarity, garch

Why is it that a GARCH(p,q) model is second-order stationary iff the sum of the coefficients $\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_q, \beta_1, ..., \beta_p$ are less than 1 while, as against the usually stronger requirements of strict stationarity, the sum of the coefficients is allowed to equal 1 to attain strict stationarity? Frankly, I do not understand how this is possible given that in the latter case there isn't even a finite unconditional variance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strict stationarity does not require existence of moments of the distribution, that is why infinite variance (due to the sum of coefficients being equal to one) is not a problem. Meanwhile, weak stationarity requires existence of the first two moments, so the variance must be finite and thus the sum of coefficients has to be below one.

Comment: Quick clarification question: Doesn't strict stationarity mean that the probability distribution doesn't change when shifting in time? Wouldn't the non-existence of moments make that condition kind of futile?

Comment: No, there exist distributions with infinite first and second moments ([Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution)) or just second moments. Take such a distribution and keep it constant over time -- you will get strict stationarity.